# CSS Selector on python, trying to select a custom attribute but it's not reading it from my script? (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, automation, css-selectors

I am trying to find the custom attribute, but I'm having a hard time understanding the issue. I am using the correct formatting, but I'm not able to call the field.

this is my code:

username_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-test-id*=login-email-input-field]').send_keys(USERNAME)

[image]

When I do a search on my inspect elements console :div[data-test-id*=login-email-input-field] I do get 1 results back, but for some reason it doesnt pass the script.

Here is the error I get:

[20724:15928:0504/094744.575:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:47:44.574] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A
device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[20724:15928:0504/094744.576:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:47:44.575] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A
device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[20724:15928:0504/094744.590:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:47:44.589] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A
device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[20724:15928:0504/094744.591:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:47:44.590] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A
device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[20724:15928:0504/094744.591:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:47:44.591] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A
device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\aaskari\source\repos\Automation_EON\Automation_EON\Automation_EON_Login_xpath.py", line 17, in 
username_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-test-id*=login-email-input-field]').send_keys(USERNAME)
File "C:\Users\aaskari\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
File "C:\Users\aaskari\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Users\aaskari\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\aaskari\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

[image]

what if I do div to input a child?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: I added it to the main question

Answer (score 0):

Change your css seletor from

```
'div[data-test-id*=login-email-input-field]'
```

to

```
"div[data-test-id='login-email-input-field']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add quotation marks (single/double) to surround the attribute value.

So something like below will work.

```
username_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-test-id*='login-email-input-field']").send_keys(USERNAME)
```

Or else you can always skip the double quotations in the locator string.

```
username_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-test-id*=\"login-email-input-field\"]").send_keys(USERNAME)
```

Comment: How does it differ from the above solution ?

Comment: @cruisepandey: More words, I guess. Though the solution is self-explanatory, the words do help.

Comment: I'm actually surprised the quotes are required. They shouldn't be, not in this case - because as the asker said, the browser dev tools do recognize the selector without quotes, and it's a valid selector. But maybe Selenium requires the quotes for whatever reason.

Comment: it's binding language that requires for parsing